# c++ binary tree, need a way to return line number the word is on, not the word number

Tags: c++, binary-tree

here is my code at current. right now i am returning the word number as it occurs when i am reading the text file in, what i need to do is return the line number the word exists on and print this out next to each word that i return to the console.  so rather than "hello world" appearing as, hello - 1 world -2, i need - hello -1  world -1

need help figuring out how to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>
#include <conio.h>

    struct node
    {
        int key_value, lineNumber;
        char *word;
        struct node *left,*right;
    };

    struct node *inserttree(struct node *tree,char *s, int lineNumber)
    {
        int i;

      if (tree==NULL)
      {
        if ( ( tree = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof(struct node) ) ) !=NULL)
        {
          if ((tree->word=(char *) malloc(strlen(s)+1))==NULL)
          {
              free(tree);
              tree=NULL;
          }
          else
          {
              tree->left=NULL;
              tree->right=NULL;
              strcpy(tree->word,s);
                tree->lineNumber = lineNumber ;
          }
        }
      }

      else if ((i=strcmp(tree->word,s))>0)
      {
          tree->left=inserttree(tree->left,s, lineNumber);
      }
      else if (i<0)
      {
          tree->right=inserttree(tree->right,s, lineNumber);
      }

      return tree;
    }

    void printtree(struct node *tree)
    {

        if (tree!=NULL)
        {
            printtree(tree->left);
            printf("%s %d\n",tree->word, tree->lineNumber);

            printtree(tree->right);
        }
    }

    //int search(struct node *tree)
    //{
    //  int key;
    //  tree->right->key_value = key;
    //  return key;
    //}

    void freetree(struct node *tree)
    {
        if (tree!=NULL)
        {
            free(tree->word);
            freetree(tree->left);
            freetree(tree->right);
            free(tree);
        }
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        FILE *f;
        char s[1024]; /*assumes a word cannot be longer than 1023 chars*/
        struct node *tree=NULL;
        int line = 1;

    if ((f=fopen("Test.txt","r"))==NULL)
        printf("Unable to open Test.txt\n");
        else
        {
            while (fscanf(f,"%1023s",s)!=EOF)
            tree=inserttree(tree,s, line++);
            fclose(f);

            printtree(tree);  //moved from inserttree
            freetree(tree);
        }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your printing happens on this line: `printf("%s %d\n",tree->word, tree->lineNumber);` Is lineNumber not being printed?

Comment: So you only need to find the correct value to pass as line number to `tree=inserttree(tree,s, line++);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a counter variable to printtree() method, and give it a 0 as initial value:

```
int count = 0;
void printtree(struct node *tree, int count)
{

    if (tree!=NULL)
    {
        printtree(tree->left, ++count);

        printf("%s %d\n",tree->word, count-1);

        printtree(tree->right, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is really close, i shifted printtree(tree->left, count++); up above the printf function, because this was breaking my alphabetizing of the output, i am still seeing a few bugs here with line numbers, it is placing the first word of the new line on the wrong line number still.  Could this be due to my call in main printtree(tree, 0); ??

Comment: hmm...the problem seems to be when i find a word left, lets say starting with the letter "b" and print it out i am incrementing, then if a char "a" is found this is being put on line 2 since we are counting up ...